# Hide a subdirectory on my website hosting

Tags: htaccess

I have a website www.mcruiseon.com. I have added .htaccess to get all www.mcruiseon.com to redirect to www.mcruiseon.com/wordpress. But the 'wordpress' still shows up on my html link on browser. Can I hide the fact that the website is hosted under a folder wordpress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understood correctly, you'll have to follow this Codex instructions: [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install).

> If you already have WordPress installed in its own folder (i.e. http://example.com/wordpress) then the steps are as follows:

If that's your case, you'll learn how to make WP work as if it were on the root, even being installed on a folder. If your actual `.htaccess` only have the redirection you mention, you can delete it, otherwise make a backup so you can merge it with the new one (from WordPress).

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the custom redirection rule you said you added in your .htaccess file.
2. In **WordPress Dashboard > Settings > General > Site Address (URL)** — change the URL to `http://www.mcruiseon.com`
3. [Read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) for more info.

Comment: Actually, that's what brasofilo said. +1 to him :)

Comment: These changes are scary :), I think I'll try it out on my test setup and then production. Thanks guys. Very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @AahanKrish, I should have left a message pointing your misreading... Cheers, +1+ two!

Comment: @brasofilo haha! nevermind! :D